A regional image
Can you draw a figure, consisting of two parts only, that would explain the image below using the colors red and blue?


Although I'd say it's basic knowledge (at least in here)

Also, it has nothing to do with the colors chosen, I just chose to use them

I can't help but wondering in what region that first blurb is called 'red' instead of 'orange'...

The answer is

 A red circle with a blue radius:
 

Reason?

 The formula represents the area of a circle πr^2 (hence the title). The reason being if red is the circumference and blue being the radius we get that formula… (circumference/(r + r))x r x r = πr^2


You got it, well done!

Extremely creative puzzle idea!!

Thanks, I actually used that paint app you suggested before :) (not that this was complicated to make of course, but now I know whenever I want to create visual puzzles)

A minor criticism if I may- the layout could be neater…
